# Can I make outbound UDP requests from an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I thought of porting my web application to Amazon's EC2 service. I have no experience with AWS and was curious whether EC2 allows you to make outbound UDP requests. My Django web application relies heavily on UDP requests this is one of my first things to consider when moving to the cloud for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Given the majority of DNS requests use UDP, it would be nonsensical for any provider not to allow you to send UDP packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, EC2 allows outbound UDP requests but you can test it yourself using the [AWS free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/).